# Why are my last runs of my scripts do not show in My Executions?

Tags: google-apps-script

Very simple, as simple as the title says.  I run my script several times at different times, one whole hour goes by and those runs do not show in My Executions.  The last run that shows is from one hour ago, all newer executions don't show.

Things I've tried:
- Delete all my temporary files from Google Chrome
- Refresh the page
- Wait for more than one hour

This is terribly hindering my coding because I cannot debug, I don't know what tripped an error, all I can see is the error as showing more information on the error itself doesn't give me the line and column number where my code blew up, only the My Executions dashboard can tell me that.

Has anyone had this issue?  Did anyone resolve it?

I've been running searches on Google for something similar and nothing shows up that is specific to this problem.

Comment: Disable V8 and use the Rhino engine if your script allows for it

Comment: try view>stackdriver error

Comment: Hello Elizabeth, just like @TheMaster has mentioned, have you tried checking the `Stackdriver Logging` from `View`? Cheers!

Comment: Thank you guys for the responses, they were all very helpful in solving my problem.  Corporate may or may not like me making changes like this and I don't even know if I have permissions to change anything so I'll consider this problem solved as now I know what's happening.  Again, thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to view the logs for your current project you should check the `Stackdriver Logs`.

This provides more information on the current executions and you can also check what has been executed and when. This also shows if there were any errors associated with your execution/s.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question @ale13.  I did notice that if I execute anything from the development environment it won't show in My Executions, but if I run it from the spreadsheet, it will.